# Hand Cursor when hover on a button in Java AWT

Tags: java, awt

I've created a button in AWT with the name "Reset".  I want the cursor to be hand cursor when the mouse is hovered on this button.

I tried the `mouseEntered` method of the `MouseAdapter` class but no effect.

```
void createResetButton() {
    Button resetButton = new Button("Reset");
    resetButton.setBounds(300, 335, 100, 40);
    add(resetButton);
    resetButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            usernameTextField.setText(null);
            passwordTextField.setText(null);
            invalidMessage.setVisible(false);   
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(HAND_CURSOR);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Thomas Fritsch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this done this way after few hits and trials:

```
void createResetButton() {
    Button resetButton = new Button("Reset");
    resetButton.setBounds(300, 335, 100, 40);
    add(resetButton);
    resetButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            usernameTextField.setText(null);
            passwordTextField.setText(null);
            invalidMessage.setVisible(false);   
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            resetButton.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(HAND_CURSOR);`
in your `mouseEntered` method had no effect,
because you only got the cursor, but then did nothing with it.

The solution is simpler than you might have expected.
You don't need your `mouseEntered` method.
Just use the [`setCursor(Cursor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setCursor-java.awt.Cursor-)  method  of class `Component`on your `resetButton`.

```
void createResetButton() {
    Button resetButton = new Button("Reset");
    resetButton.setBounds(300, 335, 100, 40);
    add(resetButton);
    resetButton.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    resetButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            usernameTextField.setText(null);
            passwordTextField.setText(null);
            invalidMessage.setVisible(false);   
        }
    });
}
```

Then AWT will do the rest for you: showing the hand cursor when the mouse
enters the `resetButton`, and showing the normal cursor when leaving it.

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas Fritsch, worked well but was showing the warning: `The field Frame.HAND_CURSOR is deprecated`. Also, I found another way.

Comment: @Genius This deprecation warning will disappear when using `Cursor.HAND_CURSOR` instead. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Worked Well!
Thanks, @Thomas Fritsch.